# How to access functions in django forms

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I need to execute onChange function on django forms radioButton. I'm unable to access the function for further process. Is it possible to execute admin functions without templates since i had defined the form in forms.py as following

forms.py

```
BoolChoices = ((0, 'Yes'), (1, 'No'))
class myForm(forms.ModelForm):
        myfield = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'size': 7, 'disabled':True}))
    option = forms.TypedChoiceField( choices=BoolChoices, widget=forms.RadioSelect(renderer=HorizontalRadioRenderer, attrs={'onchange':'check_status()'}), coerce=int)
```

Defined the function in views.py

```
def check_status(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = MyForm
    else:
        form = MyForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        opt = form.cleaned_data['option']
        if opt == 1:
            form.fields['myfield'].widget.attrs['enabled'] = True
```

What should I do to get this working??

Comment: This question is very unclear. `onChange` is a Javascript function, but you haven't shown any Javascript.

Comment: Actually I dont know how to access the function check_status defined in views.py from forms radiobutton onChange(). What should i do for this??

Comment: You need to use Ajax for that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use AJAX:

In your template:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
function check_status(){
   $.get("{% url app.views.check_status %}", function(data){
       console.log(data);
   }
}
})
```

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

This way you will execute function from views.